# meaning of „lettene“?

Tags: meaning

The word „lettene“ appears in Thomas Mann's „Joseph und seine Brüder“ (in subchapter „Das Kind der Höhle“ of Chapter 3 „Die kretische Laube“ of the last part „Joseph, der Ernährer“).  The paragraph reads like this:

> »Dieser Knecht«, antwortete Auta, indem er mit einer Hand die **lettene** Figur umwickelte und die andere gegen den König aufhob, »wird es genau machen, wie Pharao gebietet und es mich zu meinem Glück gelehrt, – der Einzige des Rê, das schöne Kind des Atôn.«

(Auta is a sculptor, and the „Figur“ is a statuette he has made of the Pharaoh's sister, „die süße Prinzessin Baketatôn“.)

A thorough web search has revealed absolutely nothing of relevance.

I don't believe this is a typo because this passage is identical in two different editions of the novel (Aufbau-Verlag 1956 and Fischer Klassik 2009).

The Russian translation conveys the „lettene Figur“ as „глиняную фигуру“, i.e. „the clay figure“.  Can I take it that „lettene“ means „made of clay“?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Grimms Wörterbuch](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=L04951) provides for substantive *Lett(en)*:

> Lehmerde, thonige Erde, thoniger Mergel (todays orthography would require *th* to be replaced by *t*)

so it means something like *clay* or *marl*, so the Russian translation seems correct. I have never encountered that word, however, so the frequency indication of [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Letten) may be a bit exaggerated.

Comment: There's a Wikipedia page for [Letten (Gestein)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letten_(Gestein)), which seems to correspond to [fire clay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_clay). So it seems to be a specific type of clay or Ton (not sure about Lehm), and the figure is probably made of this material.

Comment: The frequency indication might not be able to discern this fron the nationality *Lette, Letten* (latvian).

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: After looking at both Wikipedia articles, I'm fairly sure the identification of [Letten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letten_(Gestein)) with [fire clay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_clay) is incorrect. Fire clay is a specific kind of high quality clay used for the manufacture of heat resistant ceramics, whereas Letten seems to describe a low quality silty clay or loam that's not particularly good for ceramics of any kind — although, if the usage in the OP's quote is idiomatic, apparently it _can_ be used as a (deprecating?) term for some kind of sculpting clay too.

Comment: In Swiss German, Lett is a still common word for clay, c.f. https://digital.idiotikon.ch/p/lem/149490

Comment: "a Lett'n" is a reasonably common term in Bavarian.

Comment: Indeed, I can confirm use of this word in Austria. I found an entry in an [online collection of Austrian words](https://www.oesterreichisch.net/wort/11136/letten) that confirms this original meaning of clay, but in colloqial language/dialect it is used to refer to more "liquid" forms of earth a.k.a mud, muddy water etc.